# Best practice: How to get custom user input in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Please allow me to present a simplified version of my problem:

Lets say I have a main window called `MainWindow` in which I would like to display some `Person` objects in `MainWindow`. Now, in order to instantiate these `Person` objects I need a bunch of different fields such as name, age, profession, favourite food, etc...

Here is my solution:

I try to get all input fields and instantiate a `Person` in a secondary window and then send back the result to the main form.

`MainWindow` has a public method as follows:

```
public void (Person input) 
{
    // use the fields in input to add details to window
}
```

I have another window in the project called `PersonInput` that takes in its constructor a reference to a `MainWindow` and saves it in a field.

```
    private MainWindow owner;
    public PersonInput(MainWindow parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        owner = parent;
    }
```

`PersonInput` has a number of input fields corresponding to the required fields of a `Person` object.

in addition it has a button called "AddPerson" with an associated onClick event handler as follows: (pseudoCode)

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{     
      //get all fields from this form..
      String enteredName = this.nameText.Text; 
      //get more fields....
      Person p = new Person(...);

      //owner is MainWindow, send Back the Person so details can be displayed
      owner.addPerson(p); 
      this.Close(); 
}
```

as you would expect, `MainWindow` has a Button named "AddPersonButton" which has an on click event handler like this:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        PersonInput x = new PersonInput(this); //pass this as a reference
        //so this window can send us back the result when they have it

        x.Show(); //open the child window so user can enter information
}
```

While this method works, I am quite convinced it is not the best practice way to do it. I would like to learn the idiomatic .net WPF way of doing this. Please enlighten me

Comment: I'd start with some tutorial about databinding...

Comment: I would have hoped that as a user with almost 2k rep that you know that best practice questions are not a good fit for Stackoverflow as they generate opinionated answers.

Comment: @DavidG this is not strictly a best practice question, I simply don't know how to accomplish this task in .NET but I wanted to share my attempt anyway to let people know i have attempted something before hand.

Comment: The title starts with "Best practice" and it's again mentioned in the body. Seems pretty best practice to me!

Comment: The MVVM pattern; learn it, love it, live it. WPF was designed to take advantage of this pattern.  While you *can* do traditional code behind, you will fight WPF way more than necessary trying to use it.

Comment: `PersonInput` shouldn't know `MainWindow` exists. Give the dialog a `ShowDialog` method that returns a new instance of `Person`, or returns null if the user cancels. Write a method in `MainWindow` that shows the dialog and, if return isn't null, adds the new instance to the appropriate collection. `PersonInput.ShowDialog` could take an existing instance as a field initializer, which could be null to leave it with the defaults.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I am new to .net can you please leave me an answer with some code examples? do I still instantiate a new PersonInput then call its ShowDialog?

Comment: @ForeverStudent I'll slap something together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PersonInput.xaml.cs

```
public class PersonInput : Window
{
    public void PersonInput()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
    }

    public static Person ShowDialog(Person initializer)
    {
        var vm = new PersonViewModel(initializer);
        var dlg = new PersonInput() { DataContext = vm };

        if (dlg.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault(false))
        {
            return vm.ToPerson();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void OK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = true;
    }

    private void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = false;
    }
}
```

PersonInputViewModel.cs

```
public class PersonViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public PersonViewModel(Person person = null)
    {
        if (person != null) 
        {
            //  Assuming Person has FirstName and LastName properties
            FirstName = person.FirstName;
            LastName = person.LastName;
            //  etc. etc. for all the rest
        }
    }

    public Person ToPerson()
    {
        return new Person()
        {
            FirstName = this.FirstName,
            LastName = this.LastName,
            //  etc. etc. for all other properties
        };
    }

    private string _firstName = null;
    public string FirstName {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set {
            if (value != _firstName) {
                _firstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FirstName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModelBase.cs

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

PersonInput.xaml

```
<Window xmlns:blahblahblah="Blah blah blah" etc etc
    Title="Person" 
    Height="640" 
    Width="480"
    ShowInTaskbar="False"
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" 
    >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="180" Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">First Name</Label>
        <TextBox
            Grid.Row="0" 
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="{Binding FirstName}"
            />

        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Last Name</Label>
        <TextBox
            Grid.Row="1" 
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="{Binding LastName}"
            />

        <StackPanel 
            Orientation="Horizontal" 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            Grid.Row="10"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            >
            <Button Content="_OK" Click="OK_Click" />
            <Button Content="_Cancel" Click="Cancel_Click" />
        </StackPanel>                
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest weakness of this approach is the strong coupling between MainWindow and PersonInput.

A slightly better approach would be to use Observer Pattern and have the Main Window anonymously subscribe.

**Simple solution example code:**

```
public interface IAddPersonObserver
{
    void OnPersonAdded(Person person);
}

public interface IAddPersonObservable
{
    void Subscribe(IAddPersonObserver observer);
    void Unsubscribe(IAddPersonObserver observer);
}

public class MainWindow : IAddPersonObserver
{
    ...

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PersonInput x = new PersonInput(); 
        x.Subscribe(this);
        x.Show();
    }

    public void OnPersonAdded(Person addedPerson)
    {
        addPerson(addedPerson); // or whatever view update code you want
    }
}
```

Further improvements would revolve around separating the MainWindow from knowing what view gets created or shown, and having an intermediary object (such as a PersonRepository) store/hold/provide the important business data. This is much better than having the application data actually live inside the Views and Application Windows.

Comment: Best practice is to define an interface IBestPracticeProvider which you can query for an IInterfaceProvider which you query for an IInterfaceObserverInterface which interfaces with arbitrary interface observation interfaces and injects dependencies into the dependency objector via the InterdepencyAdaptorObjectorInjectorInterface factory. Either that, or just write a PersonDialog that returns a new Person instance, and any arbitrary caller can do whatever he likes with it. Like, you know, programming.

Comment: It seems that you have a vendetta against Object-Oriented programming. Just because you aren't interested in certain types of solutions doesn't mean that the rest of us shouldn't focus on trying to improve our code.

Comment: I love OOP. But since I work with this stuff for a living, I have little patience with gratuitous complexity. Do you intend for OP to add a discrete interface implementation to MainWindow for *every possible Add* dialog that MainWindow might display*? Or just this one? Can you explain what your scheme would actually accomplish that simple "get object from function" semantics would not? And if it *is* a good idea, why isn't it generic? `IAddObserver<T>`/`IAddObservable<T>` makes a lot more sense than copy/pasting six of each. Or writing a snippet.

Comment: This particular response was tailored to the OP, who might not be sufficiently experienced to work well with generics and highly abstract solutions. Therefore, I provided a simple concrete sample that would begin the process of decoupling and thinking about dependency inversion. While there are much more scalable solutions (as I hinted at in my post), it didn't seem that throwing out of a bunch of pattern names would be helpful to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Another use MVVM practice:

[Solution structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KcbV.png)

```
public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}

public class PersonListViewModel : DependencyObject {
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Items { get; set; }

    public Person CurrentPerson
    {
        get { return (Person)GetValue(CurrentPersonProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CurrentPersonProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentPersonProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentPerson", typeof(Person), typeof(PersonListViewModel));

    public ICommand AddCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand EditCommand { get; set; }

    public PersonListViewModel() {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        AddCommand = new RelayCommand(p=> add() );
        EditCommand = new RelayCommand(p=> { return CurrentPerson != null; }, p => edit());
    }

    private void add() {
        Person p= new Person();
        p.Id = Items.Count();
        p.Name = "New Name";
        p.Birthday = DateTime.Now;
        Items.Add(p);
    }

    private void edit() {
        var viewModel = new PersonItemViewModel(CurrentPerson);
        var view = new View.PersonEditWindow();
        view.DataContext = viewModel;
        view.Show(); 
    }
}

public class PersonItemViewModel : DependencyObject {
    Person person;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(PersonItemViewModel) );

    public DateTime Birthday
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(BirthdayProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BirthdayProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BirthdayProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Birthday", typeof(DateTime), typeof(PersonItemViewModel));

    public PersonItemViewModel() {

    }
    public PersonItemViewModel(Person source) {
        this.person = source;

        Name =  person.Name;
        Birthday = person.Birthday;
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);

        if (e.Property == NameProperty) {
            person.Name = (string) e.NewValue;
        }

        if (e.Property == BirthdayProperty) {
            person.Birthday = (DateTime)e.NewValue;
        }
    }
}
```

List Form:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.View.PersonListWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.View"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    Title="PersonListWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModel"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModel:PersonListViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    >

<Grid Margin="8">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPerson, Mode=TwoWay}">
    </DataGrid>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Height="32" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Margin="4" Command="{Binding AddCommand}">Add</Button>
        <Button Margin="4" Command="{Binding EditCommand}">Edit</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Edit Form:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.View.PersonEditWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.View"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="PersonEditWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
            xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModel"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModel:PersonItemViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"

    >
<Grid Margin="20">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0">Name</TextBlock>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBox>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">Birthday</TextBlock>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Birthday}"></TextBox>

</Grid>
```

[Results (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkq9K.png)